# Disable error: nouveau unknown i2c port and unknown status

Tags: linux-mint, nouveau, lmde

I am running Linux Mint Debian Edition, and I am getting the following errors:

```
Jul 25 10:23:39 mhost kernel: [   36.775380] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown i2c port 57
Jul 25 10:23:39 mhost kernel: [   36.775406] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown i2c port 49
Jul 25 10:23:39 mhost kernel: [   37.095951] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: PFIFO: unknown status 0x40000000
Jul 25 10:23:57 mhost kernel: [   54.815320] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown i2c port 48
```

Otherwise, my system is fine. Everything seems to be working properly, the only problem is, that I get these errors very frequently and have to clean the logs regularly (kern.log, syslog, and messages).

I am not too interested in fixing the underlying issue (I do not like to mess with the graphics driver if I do not have to), but I would like to block the error (unknown i2c port as well as unknown status).

Here is some more information about my system:

```
$ inxi -SGx
System:    Host: mhost Kernel: 3.2.0-4-amd64 x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.6.3) Desktop: Cinnamon 2.0.14  Distro: LinuxMint 1 debian
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GF108 [GeForce GT 630] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
           X.Org: 1.14.3 drivers: nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NVC1 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.2 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

So my question are:

- Can I block a certain error in Linux?
- And more specifically, can I block/disable these errors?

My main motivation for this is that my log files become really big really fast which fills up my disk. One workaround would be to automatically clear the logs, but I do not want to put that much strain on my ssd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution here: [not logging certain errors](http://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/)

I just had to add this line at the top of `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
:msg, contains, "nouveau" ~
```

It seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can block the errors from showing by using grep -v like this:

```
grep -v 'nouveau 0000:01:00.0' [your log file] | less
```

You could also make a script that whipes the log files for you and let it run at bootup.

make scriptfile:

```
sudo nano /root/cleanlogs
```

The script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash          
grep -v 'nouveau 0000:01:00.0' /var/log/messages > messages.new
mv messages.new /var/log/messages

grep -v 'nouveau 0000:01:00.0' /var/log/kern.log > kern.log.new.new
mv kern.log.new /var/log/kern.log

//other log files same way
```

make executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /root/cleanlogs
```

To run the script at boot there are different ways depending on your linux distribution, best you google it. As far as I know there is no way of not logging it at all, but this way you don't have to clean the files manually.

the error will go away updating the nouveau driver, current version dousn't fully support your card yet.

Comment: I meant blocking it from getting into the log file in the first place. My main problem is that I have giant log files which I need to clear a lot. But this would definitely help in seeing other errors in the log files.

Comment: just saw your edit. thanks. not exactly what I was looking for, but still helpful. I was now able to also find a way to prevent these error messages from being logged completely.